# Continuous time series classification with lstm in Keras?

Tags: time-series, classification, lstm, keras, online-algorithms

I have been researching [time series classification with LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-rnn-models-for-human-activity-recognition-time-series-classification/). I've seen examples where they provide continuous predictions, i.e. the prediction is updated at each time step. Is it possible to train a multivariate LSTM to make predictions on partial data (i.e. "as it comes in"). So it would be trained on the full set of timesteps, but then would provide classification prediction at timestep 1, then at timestamp 2, with performance hopefully increasing as time goes on. I found a paper doing something similar [Predicting Learning Status in MOOCs using LSTM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.01616.pdf) where predictions were made on a weekly basis for a particular class using (I believe) a single LSTM network. However, it is light on details, so if anyone can provide any further information, examples that would be much appreciated.